# Xsl anchor attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml file code is as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<testimonials>
    <item>
        <author-name>xyz</author-name>
        <author-url>http://xyz.net</author-url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <author-name>abcde</author-name>
        <author-url>http://abc.org</author-url>
    </item>

</testimonials>
```

The xsl file code looks as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/xmlfile">
    <xsl:for-each select="item">

    <li>
        <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="author-url"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="author-url"/>
        </a>

    </li>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i try to use these xml file, I am not getting anchor tags, I simply see text output as

xyz http://xyz.net abcde http://abc.org

please let me know if i have to make any chnages so that I am able to see anchor tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
<xsl:template match="/xmlfile">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="/testimonials">
```